# Typing break with Awesome WM

Tags: software-rec, awesome, typing-break

Is there a program that implements typing breaks that works with the Awesome Window Manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Xwrits`](http://www.lcdf.org/xwrits/) works with Awesome. It's a simple command line program. Here's an example for a five-minute break with screen lock every 55 minutes:

```
xwrits breaktime=5:00 typetime=55:00 +mouse +lock
```

Answer (score 3):

[Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/)  is another tool, it will help you to take care of your hands, posture and eyes.